# Go get cannot find local packages when using multiple modules in a repo

Tags: go, module, go-modules

I'm having issues with go's new module system, as I'd like to define a local module and import it in the main program. The local package resides in a folder of the main package/root folder. Imagine the following project structure outside the `$GOPATH`.

### Project structure

./main.go

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "example.com/localModule/model"

func main() {
    var p = model.Person{name: "Dieter", age:25}
    fmt.Printf("Hello %s\n", p.name)
}
```

./model/person.go

```
package model

type Person struct {
    name string
    age int
}
```

In the root folder I initialized a module by calling

```
go mod init example.com/localModule
```

In the `model/` folder I then initialized the submodule by calling

```
go mod init example.com/localModule/model
```

### The error

In the root folder calling the following commands fail.

```
$ go get
go build example.com/localModule/model: no Go files in

$ go build
main.go:4:8: unknown import path "example.com/localModule/model": cannot find module providing package example.com/localModule/model
```

The error message for go get is cut off, I din't parse it wrongly.

I do not plan on pushing the module to a server and and just needed a way of referencing the local package `model`, so I chose `example.com/localModule/` and `example.com/localModule/model` respectively.

I'm using `go1.11 darwin/amd64` on a Macbook running MacOS 10.13.6.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can have local "sub" modules like you ask for by adding a require statement and a matching replace statement with a relative file path in go.mod.

*In the "root" ./go.mod:*

```
module example.com/localModule

require example.com/localModule/model v0.0.0

replace example.com/localModule/model v0.0.0 => ./model
```

Comment: This is one possible solution, but it is a more complex solution than the more common approach of one module per repository, which avoids this error and problem.

Comment: Note that there are definitely some [footguns](https://github.com/ugorji/go/issues/299) with a multi-module repo approach, so anyone considering a `replace` + multi-module repo approach as outlined in this answer should carefully evaluate other options before going down that path. Some more details in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55735453/11210494).

Answer (score 8):

#### Root problem

The reason you are getting this error is because you have defined two modules that do not know how to find each other on your local disk.

```
$ go build
main.go:4:8: unknown import path "example.com/localModule/model": 
 cannot find module providing package example.com/localModule/model
```

#### Solution 1: `replace`

You can add a `replace` directive to the top module's `go.mod` file, such as:

`replace example.com/localModule/model v0.0.0 => ./model`

which lets the top module find the other module on disk. This is covered in more detail in the [replace FAQ](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#when-should-i-use-the-replace-directive) and ["Multi-module repositories"](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#faqs--multi-module-repositories) section on the Modules wiki.

However, this is a more complex solution, can be hard to get right, is usually more on-going work, and has some limitations like `replace` is ignored for all modules except the current module. For most people, a multi-module repo is probably is not what they want. It is relatively rare at this point to really need to have multiple modules in a single repository.

#### Solution 2: one repo == one module

While it is possible to use a `replace` directive, the more common and straightforward solution is:

- Have a single `go.mod` file in your repository, and
- Place that single `go.mod` file in the root of your repository.

This is a very simple solution, and it means your two packages within the repository will be able to find each other automatically without needing any `replace`, and which avoids the error message you reported.

#### `replace` with multi-module repo, vs. single module repo?

Russ Cox commented in [#26664](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/26664#issuecomment-455232444):

> For all but power users, you probably want to adopt the usual convention that one repo = one module. It's important for long-term evolution of code storage options that a repo *can* contain multiple modules, but it's almost certainly not something you want to do by default.

If you instead want to have multiple modules defined within a single repository, there is a fair amount of nuance about how to do so properly, and there is an [entire section](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#faqs--multi-module-repositories) of the Modules wiki that should be read about how to manage the complexity associated with multiple modules in a single repository, including this advice:

> Adding modules, removing modules, and versioning modules with multiple modules in a single repository *requires considerable care and deliberation, so it is almost always easier and simpler to manage a single-module repository* rather than multiple modules in an existing repository.

Comment: Does option 2 `one repo == one module` mean that all go-files (here `./main.go` and `./model/person.go`) have to use the same package name (for example `package myAwesomeApp`) ?

Answer (score 0):

for me below commands worked

create go.mod `go mod init "github.com/udacity/ud615/app/health"`

and then download other modules as `go mod tidy`